# bootstrap multiple floated divs vertically centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel and in it's heading I have a heading title which should go to the left and a select as well as a date range input which should go on the right of the panel heading vertically aligned in the middle. This is what I managed to do so far, the problem is the select item which is not vertically aligned.

[image]

Here is my code in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prxbl/5ca3xo0b/8/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="comenzi-chart">
        Heading
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
          <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
          <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
        </div>
        <div class="select-chart-type">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Daily</option>
            <option>Weekly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-daterange {
    width: 250px;
    bottom: 5px;  
    float: right;
}

.select-chart-type {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.select-chart-type select {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

I am probably taking the wrong approach here so feel free to suggest the right way to do this. In the end I would like to be able to insert buttons/selects/inputs/ in this panel heading and they should all follow each other, float right and be vertically aligned in the middle.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check below answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-top: -5px;` on `.select-chart-type` this class..

***OR***

Use `position: relative;bottom: 5px;` on `.select-chart-type` this class..

Comment: Using position: relative;bottom: 5px; on .select-chart-type worked.

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do like the right `input` and use `position: relative;` and `bottom : 5px`

```
.select-chart-type {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px; 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ca3xo0b/11/)

Comment: This works, it's the same solution as proposed by @Sunil Gehlot but I have accepted his answer because it was first.

Answer (score 2):

Add this css in this class".select-chart-type"

```
.select-chart-type {
  bottom: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

See [UPDETED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ca3xo0b/9/)

Comment: This works, it's the same solution as proposed by @Sunil Gehlot but I have accepted his answer because it was first.

Comment: @jainam can you please start adding the main lines/point too in your answer rather then posting full code??